# Constructor error when initializing c++ vector with struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct, c++14

I am trying to initialize a vector of struct `opcodeTable` with 2 values as follow:

```
struct opcodeTableE {
        uint16_t opcode;
        uint16_t mask;
        void (chipCpu::*instruction)(uint16_t);
};

std::vector<opcodeTableE> opcodetable{
        {0x00E0, 0xFFFF, chipCpu::clearScreen},
        {0x00EE, 0xFFFF, chipCpu::returnFromSub}
};
```

But I get the following error:

```
no instance of constructor "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector [with _Tp=chipCpu::opcodeTableE, _Alloc=std::allocator<chipCpu::opcodeTableE>]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: ({...}, {...})
```

NOTE: I am on C++14

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `operator&` to get the pointer to member function. e.g.

```
std::vector<opcodeTableE> opcodetable{
        {0x00E0, 0xFFFF, &chipCpu::clearScreen},
        {0x00EE, 0xFFFF, &chipCpu::returnFromSub}
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/L3TT0Z0Ph9DUsLyf)

BTW: `operator&` is only optional when getting pointer to non-member function or static member function because of the function-to-pointer implicit conversion.

Comment: Here is what I got after doing it: 
`error: could not convert '{{224, 65535, &chipCpu::clearScreen}, {238, 65535, &chipCpu::returnFromSub}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<chipCpu::opcodeTableE>'`

Comment: @KnoxRoot Could you make an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which could be used to reproduce the error? I tried to make one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and it works fine.